# Finding minimum value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with grades. When I ask for the minimum value it gives me the largest value. I used the `min(Grades)` to find the minimum but it was me the largest then I found `min(Grades.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])` and it worked but I don't get why the min(Grades) doesn't work. I also have no idea how the `min(Grades.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])` works and what it means.

```
>>> Grades
{'pr': [17, 15], 'hw': [16, 27, 25], 'ex': [83, 93], 'qz': [8, 10, 5]}
>>> min(Grades)
'ex'
>>> min(Grades.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
('qz', [8, 10, 5])
```

Comment: You're printing the dictionary that has the minimal value (in this case, minimum list).

Comment: @falsetru is right. in second case `min(Grades.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])` you are comparing first values of list

Comment: it always returns 'ex' as the minimum but when i change it to something other than 'ex' it works

Comment: If you are trying to find the minimum value in the dictionary for all the lists (which is 5), you need to iterate over each dictionary key, and then iterate over each list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterating dictionary yields keys, not (key, value) pairs.

```
>>> d = {'pr': [17, 15], 'hw': [16, 27, 25], 'ex': [83, 93], 'qz': [8, 10, 5]}
>>> list(d)
['pr', 'qz', 'hw', 'ex']

>>> min(_)
'ex'
```

[`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) on the dictionary returns the key that is largest (lexicographically).

---

**Meaning of `min(Grades.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])`**

`min` accepts optional `key` parameter. The return value of the `key` function is used to compare order of items, instead of the original values.

The parameter `x` of the `lambda` is each item passed to the function. `('pr', [17, 15])`, `('hw', [16, 27, 25])`, ...; So the second items (`x[1]`) in the tuples are compared instead of the tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
minScore = 100
lowInitial = ""
grades = {'pr': [17, 15], 'hw': [16, 27, 25], 'ex': [83, 93], 'qz': [8, 10, 5]}
for initials, scores in grades.items():
    lowestScore = min(scores)
    if lowestScore < minScore:
        minScore = lowestScore
        lowInitial = initials
print("Person with lowest score is: " + lowInitial)
print("Lowest score was: " + str(minScore))

Person with lowest score is: qz
Lowest score was: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also find the `key` with the `min` values using `dictionary comprehension`

```
d = {k for k,v in grades.items() if v == min(grades.values())}
```

Output:

```
set(['qz'])
```